# VB.net: Error al cerrar Socket servidor

Tags: vb.net, .net, websocket

Buenas tardes, primero os comento los recursos que estoy utilizando con pequeñas modificaciones.

1. Servidor de `sockets` lo he cogido de este manual.
   http://www.elguille.info/colabora/puntoNET/PabloTilli_SocketsVBNET.htm
2. El cliente estoy utilizando la versión de `visual studio 2010` de esta página web.
   http://www.ajpdsoft.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=579

He conseguido enviar mensajes desde ambos lados, el problema que tengo es que cuando cierro el servidor con la x se me queda `visual studio` ejecutándose, imagino que sera porque hay algún hilo por ahí funcionando pero no debería ser no?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que efectivamente el problema está en que estás cerrando el formulario (servidor), lo cual termina el hilo donde este corre, pero eso no necesariamente cierra los hilos abiertos por él: cuando cierras la aplicación (con la X) se termina el hilo principal y cualquier hilo "de fondo" (Background Thread), pero esto no termina los hilos "de frente" (Foreground Thread).

De la [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) tenemos:

> Once all foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads are stopped and do not complete
> ...
>
> By default, the following threads execute in the foreground (that is, their IsBackground property returns false):
>
> - The primary thread (or main application thread).
> - All threads created by calling a Thread class constructor.

## Solución:

Lo más simple es que al crear el hilo le indiques que es un hilo "de fondo":

```
tcpThd = New Thread(AddressOf EsperarCliente)
tcpThd.IsBackground = True
tcpThd.Start()
```

De este modo, al cerrarse todos los hilos de frente (en tu caso solo uno: el principal), todos los hilos de fondo se cerrarán inmediatamente (el CLR se encarga de terminarlos).

Como nota adicional: toma en cuenta que el artículo de El Guille es de hace 12 años! no necesariamente sea la forma más eficiente/segura de hacer lo que quieres actualmente (aunque está bien si solo estás practicando).

Comment: Es la manera mas "sencilla que he encontrado para jugar con sockets. Quizas, haya otras mejores, me puedes indicar alguna pagina de referencia?, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Seguia sin cerrarse, as que lo hque hecho ha sido en el formclosingPrivate Sub frmPpal_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As `FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing`
        `WinSockServer.Cerrar()`
    `End Sub`
y en el proceso Cerrar he cambiado un orden y he añadido el cierre del thread. Quizas no sea muy ortodoxo, o nada.... pero bueno...
`For Each InfoClienteActual In Clientes.Values
            Call CerrarThread(IDClienteActual)
            Call Cerrar(InfoClienteActual.Socket.RemoteEndPoint)
        Next`

Answer (score 1):

Este código he utilizado en el procedimiento de cierre, al que he llamado desde el formclosing, No sera la forma mas ortodoxa, pero funciona.

`Public Sub Cerrar()
    Dim InfoClienteActual As InfoDeUnCliente

    For Each InfoClienteActual In Clientes.Values
        Call CerrarThread(IDClienteActual)
        Call Cerrar(InfoClienteActual.Socket.RemoteEndPoint)
    Next
End Sub`